# Log4j 2.6 (properties file) with Spring Boot 1.3.5 (gradle) not working

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, log4j2

Ive been trying to use *Log4j 2.6* (properties file) with *Spring Boot 1.3.5 version* and the Spring's default logging kicks in. I haven't been able to trace out the exact issue.

Here is my **build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.1.1"
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.3.0-milestone.1'
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE") 
    }
}

...

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.3.5.RELEASE'
    providedRuntime group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '1.3.5.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '1.3.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '0.10.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2', version: '1.3.5.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.6'

    testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.8.8'
    testCompile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160212'
    testCompile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.22.2'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '1.3.5.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.11', version: '0.10.1.0'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    providedRuntime
}
```

This is my **log4j2.properties** file:

```
name = PropertiesConfig

property.logDir = logs
property.filename = ingestion
property.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

appenders = console, rolling

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = ${pattern}

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${logDir}/${filename}.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${logDir}/${filename}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = ${pattern}
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

loggers = rolling

logger.rolling.name = com.dir.mysubdir
logger.rolling.level = WARN
#logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRefs = rolling
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

# Root logger option
rootLogger.level = WARN
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

I've looked into multiple SO topics on this and seem to have all the properties set correctly. But some how i'm not able to find out why it isn't logging to file and console as per my configuration.

An *empty* log file **logs/ingestion.log** as configured in the *log4j2.properties* file gets created when I bootRun the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Itseems like I had missed out including the *logging config file* parameter in **application.properties** file, because of which the log4j was detected and loaded without any error but not used by spring-boot.
Adding the below line solved the issue.

```
logging.config= # location of logging config file
```

[*P.S.*]: Found the solution to my problem from this: [log4j2.xml loaded but not applied [JVM argument]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076778/log4j2-xml-loaded-but-not-applied-jvm-argument)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot then you can configure logging in `application.properties` or `application.yml`.

**yml configuration**

```
logging:
    file: server.log
    level:
         'com.myapp': INFO
```

**properties configuration**

```
logging.file=server.log
logging.level.com.myapp=INFO
```

refer http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html for more details

Comment: I would like to use `log4j2.properties` file itself to configure logging. Shouldn't the `'spring-boot-starter-log4j2'` dependency take care of that?